# Convert array of strings in json to normal String array in java

Tags: java, android, json

Here is the response from web service:

```json
{"courses":["Bca Graphics","OS","DBMS","dnn"]}
```

I want to parse the courses array to Java String array? I tried, but I amnot able to find a solution.

Comment: Are you using any specific JSON parser library?

Comment: no, i am new to development, i am current learning, using volley to send api request from android to php server and handling response using getString method.

Comment: Then I would recommend taking a look into that. Research will always give you a better understanding than a solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [org.json.JSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html), you can do something like this:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"courses\":[\"Bca Graphics\",\"OS\",\"DBMS\",\"dnn\"]}";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONArray("courses");
List<String> strings = jsonArray.toList().stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson here.

```
String inputJson = "{\"courses\":[\"Bca Graphics\",\"OS\",\"DBMS\",\"dnn\"]}";
Gson gSon = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY).create();
MyPojo myPojo = gSon.fromJson(inputJson, MyPojo.class);
System.out.println(myPojo.getCourses());
```

POJO

```
public class MyPojo {
    public List<String> courses;
    public List<String> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
    public void setCourses(List<String> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```